# Assign a value if dataframe element differ

Tags: r, pandas, dataframe, compare

What is the equivalent Python/Pandas for the following R commands?

```
matrix1[!matrix2] <- 0
```

The goal is to compare two matrices, if the elements are different a zero should be assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the DataFrame [where](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) method:

```
In [11]: df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

In [12]: df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 5]])

In [13]: df1.where(df1 == df2, 0)
Out[13]: 
   0  1
0  1  2
1  3  0
```

to do this inplace (modifying `df`):

```
In [14]: df.where(df==df1, 0, inplace=True)
```